# proper use of worksheetfunction.countifs in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I'm working on a bit of code to pull data out of test result files, and summarize the data in its meaningful bits in an excel file because everyone who could end up looking at the data has excel.

I have the data listed out in a sheet in a file where A through M is the data and U through AB is a summary table. Column B holds the year and month a test took place formatted as `YYMM` and column L holds whether the test passed or failed "PASS" or "FAIL" I am trying to execute the code below where I am using a `dateitem`, in my example below it is January of 2017, as a criteria for the range representing column B and using "F*" as a criteria for range representing column L

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Dim xlapp As Application = New Application()
Dim xlworkbook As Workbook
Dim xlworksheet As Worksheet
dim last_row as integer

with xlworksheet   

    last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(XlDirection.xlUp).row

    Dim year_month_range As Range
    Dim pf_range As Range

    year_month_range = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(last_row, 2))
    pf_range = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(last_row, 12))

    Dim dateitem as integer
    dateitem = 1701

    .Cells(j, 27) = xlapp.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(year_month_range, dateitem, pf_range, "F*")
end with
```

Its throwing back a kind of ambiguous exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: CountIfs method of WorksheetFunction class failed*

I am using this data and using other Worksheet Functions successfully just above and below my attempt to use `countifs()` so I know that the workbook and worksheet are declared and initialized correctly. I fear there may just be some critical piece of information that I'm lacking regarding the use of `countifs()`

Comment: Do you want the COUNTIFS formula in the output or just the value or the formula?

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be like this....`Cells(j, 27).Value` or .`Cells(j, 27).FormulaR1C1`

Comment: If the column is PASS or FAIL then why are you bothering with F* instead of just using FAIL. Seems like it will be more readable this way.

Comment: The value that is returned would suffice, and I did .Cells(#,#)=.AverageIf() in some other spots and that worked exactly as I expected which is why I think it has to do with my implementation of .countifs(). You're right though, I should just right FAIL.

Comment: It looks ok to me. Does changing it to "Fail" fix it? Did you use the same implementation for AveragIF? I mean the `range = Cells(#, #)` as opposed to `Cells("A1:A100")`

Comment: So this:  
    .Cells(j, 26) = xlapp.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(year_month_range, dateitem)

works.

Comment: Can pfRange span columns? Does CountIFS work this way? `pf_range = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(last_row, 12))`

Comment: It can, I tested it in Excel...

Comment: @MichaelZ., the criteria range can span multiple columns.  However from the documentation: `"Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as the criteria_range1 argument. The ranges do not have to be adjacent to each other.`  So the fact that the two criteria ranges are not the same size is likely the issue.

Comment: crazy thing; that was a typo it should have been `(2, 12) ` and I know that in Excel `countifs()` can span columns but when I changed it to `(2,12)` it worked. I think its because pf_range and year_month_range overlapped but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @TnTinMn Excellent observation and research!

Comment: @TnTinMn, you're right. if you post it as an answer to the question I'll accept it as answer to close this. It works like that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842):

> Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as
>   the criteria_range1 argument. The ranges do not have to be adjacent to
>   each other.

Change:

```
pf_range = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(last_row, 12))
```

to:

```
pf_range = .Range(.Cells(2, 12), .Cells(last_row, 12))
```